# AngularJS - Custom directives - one gives error "Template must have exactly one root element" while other works

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

here is my **index.html**

```
<html ng-app="dempApp">
<head>
<!-- CSS -->
</head>
<body>
<div ng-switch on="templateHeader">
            <div ng-switch-when="login">
                <div loginheader></div>
            </div>

            <div ng-switch-when="home">
                <div homeheader></div>

            </div>
        </div>
</body>
<!-- JS scripts -->
</html>
```

My **app.js** has the directives

```
demoClientApp.directive('loginheader', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl:'views/loginheader.html'
      }
})

demoClientApp.directive('homeheader', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl:'views/homeheader.html'
      }
})
```

**loginheader.html** is like following

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="login-container">
                    <div class="center">
                        <h1>
                            <span class="blue">DemoApplication</span>
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="position-relative">
                        <div ng-view></div>
                    </div><!-- /position-relative -->
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div>
</div><!-- /.main-container -->
```

It has **ng-view** inside and similarly for homeheader directive I have another html file which also has ng-view.

Based on path, I am setting value of `templateHeader` and its switching the directive. But the page is blank now and shows error.

```
Error: Template must have exactly one root element. was: <div class="main-container">
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="login-container">
                        <div class="center">
                            <h1>
                                <span class="blue">DemoApplication</span>
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                    <div class="position-relative">
                        <div ng-view></div>
                    </div><!-- /position-relative -->
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div>
</div><!-- /.main-container -->
```

If I don't use the **loginheader** directive and use the html directly, it is working fine and the other **homeheader** directive is working. Why is that?

How to solve it?

**UPDATE 1**

It is working. But the problem is when the path is just `localhost:9000` it is not redirecting to login. Earlier it used to route to login if the user enters a wrong path or not logged in. So now when I just type the url `localhost:9000`, it is showing the blank page and the error. Here is how I route.

```
var demoClientApp=angular.module('demoClientApp', ['ngCookies']);

demoClientApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    })
    .when('/register', {
        templateUrl: 'register.html',
        controller: 'RegisterController'
      })
    .when('/home', {
       templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
       controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
    })

    .otherwise({
       redirectTo: '/login'
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Can you remove the comment `<!-- /.main-container -->` ?

Comment: I removed it already. I tried adding a new div wrapping all other elements in that html file also. No use.

Comment: You need to provide more code. It works fine for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/M4KMAV1brVKtP5IAIp8G?p=preview

Comment: Please see my **UPDATE 1**.

Comment: using routes with `ng-view` nested inside `ng-switch` is something I never tested, and it would probably fail. Please provide a plunker so I can test your app. What version of angular you use?

Comment: make sure you include `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` in addition to and after `ui-bootstrap.js` is loaded